# WLclient is not getting initialised

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to create a android application using native api application in worklight.I created the client it was success, but got the error message like 
' WLClient.invokeProcedure() will not be executed because WLCLient is not initialized, ensure WLCLient.connect function has been called.
 '

### Steps used

1) First i created a natvie api appklication 
2) Create and configured an Android native application
3) Initializing the WLCLient
4) Invoking a Worklight procedure
5) Receiving a procedure response

using the documantation **ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_09_2_-_Android_Development_Using_Worklight_API_in_a_Native_Application.pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In native applications you are indeed required to implement and call the `connect()` method before attempting to call the `invokeProcedure` method in the `connect`'s onSuccess.

Notes:

1. The adapter and NativeAPI must be deployed to the server to get a response back
2. The native application's wlcient.properties file must point to the server host address

It is also expected that you'll share at least *some code snippets of what you've actually implemented and the full error stack* in order to debug the error.

That said, review the Getting Started sample application created just for this. Read the tutorial and review and implementation in the native project. The studio project is required in order to deploy the adapter and app artifacts to the server.

- Training module:  [Invoking adapter procedures from native Android applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_08_Invoking_adapter_procedures_from_native_Android_applications.pdf)
- [native project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/InvokingAdapterProceduresiOSProject.zip), [studio project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/InvokingAdapterProceduresNativeProject.zip)
- [See all Getting Started training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html) for Worklight 6.2

Note that you are linking to documentation for Worklight 5.0.5; if you are using a newer version of Worklight like Worklight 6.0, 6.1 or 6.2, *you cannot use that old documentation. Use the one I've pointed to.*

Comment: Are you really using Worklight 5.0.5? Also, the steps you've added are meaningless w/out **the actual code you've written** and the **full error stack from LogCat**.

Comment: WLClient client =WLClient.createInstance(this);
client.connect( new MyConnectListener());
// creating aadapter to get data from client
String adapterName = "loginAdapter"; 
String procedureName = "getauthentication";
 WLProcedureInvocationData invocationData= new WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName, procedureName); Object [] parameters = new Object[]{"*" ,"**" ,3,false};
 invocationData.setParameters(parameters);
WLRequestOptions options= new WLRequestOptions();
options.setTimeout(5000);
client= WLClient.getInstance();
client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, new MyInvokeListner(),options);

Comment: this is the code snippet i used here i got the error like 'WLClient.invokeProcedure() will not be executed because WLCLient is not initialized, ensure WLCLient.connect function has been called'

Comment: i m using 6.2 version

Comment: So why are you looking at documentation for 5.0.5? please **look at the sample application I've linked in my answer**. It will show you how to properly implement this. **read the training module I linked you to. It is the updated module for 6.2**

Comment: Read *all of my answer*, and then click the *edit* in your question and provide everything that I've asked for.

Comment: @IdanAdar i have 6.1 sdk and i tried the demo code for connect with myadapter but it told me that invokeProcedure() will not be executed because WLCLient is not initialized, ensure WLCLient.connect function has been called